# Switch between :global and :local css modules for animating elements using sass mixins

Tags: css, sass, css-animations, scss-mixins

I wanted to switch between :global and :local while using keyframes and animation and the below given code works:

```
@mixin keyframe ($animation_name, $isGlobal: false) {
  @if $isGlobal {
    @-webkit-keyframes :global(#{$animation_name}) {
      @content;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes :global(#{$animation_name}) {
      @content;
    }

    @keyframes :global(#{$animation_name}) {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @else {
    @-webkit-keyframes #{$animation_name} {
      @content;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes #{$animation_name} {
      @content;
    }

    @keyframes #{$animation_name} {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

@mixin animation (
  $animation_name,
  $duration,
  $isGlobal: false,
  $animation_timing_function: linear,
  $delay: 0,
  $fillmode: forwards,
  $direction: normal,
) {
  @if $isGlobal {
    :global {
      -webkit-animation-name: $animation_name;
      -webkit-animation-duration: $duration;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: $animation_timing_function;
      -webkit-animation-delay: $delay;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: $fillmode;
      -webkit-animation-direction: $direction;

      -moz-animation-name: $animation_name;
      -moz-animation-duration: $duration;
      -moz-animation-timing-function: $animation_timing_function;
      -moz-animation-delay: $delay;
      -moz-animation-fill-mode: $fillmode;
      -moz-animation-direction: $direction;

      animation-name: $animation_name;
      animation-duration: $duration;
      animation-timing-function: $animation_timing_function;
      animation-delay: $delay;
      animation-fill-mode: $fillmode;
      animation-direction: $direction;
    }
  }
  @else {
    -webkit-animation-name: $animation_name;
    -webkit-animation-duration: $duration;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: $animation_timing_function;
    -webkit-animation-delay: $delay;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: $fillmode;
    -webkit-animation-direction: $direction;

    -moz-animation-name: $animation_name;
    -moz-animation-duration: $duration;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: $animation_timing_function;
    -moz-animation-delay: $delay;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: $fillmode;
    -moz-animation-direction: $direction;

    animation-name: $animation_name;
    animation-duration: $duration;
    animation-timing-function: $animation_timing_function;
    animation-delay: $delay;
    animation-fill-mode: $fillmode;
    animation-direction: $direction;
  }
}
```

But as you can observe, a number of lines of code seem to repeat. I tried a method to reduce the duplication but it doesn't seem to work as the code get's localized:

```
@mixin keyframe ($animation_name, $isGlobal: false) {
  $updated_animation_name: $animation_name;

  @if $isGlobal {
    $updated_animation_name: (:global(#{$animation_name}));
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes #{$updated_animation_name} {
    @content;
  }

  @-moz-keyframes #{$updated_animation_name} {
    @content;
  }

  @keyframes #{$updated_animation_name} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

Is there a solution to minimize the line of code? Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `@mixin keyframe`, you can do that:

```
@mixin keyframe ($animation_name, $isGlobal: false) {
  @if $isGlobal {
     $animation_name: #{':global('+$animation_name+')'};
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes #{$animation_name} {
     @content;
  }

  @-moz-keyframes #{$animation_name} {
     @content;
  }

  @keyframes #{$animation_name} {
     @content;
  }
}
```

You can optimize it even more with a loop to add prefixes:

```
@mixin keyframe ($animation_name, $isGlobal: false) {
  @if $isGlobal {
    $animation_name: #{':global('+$animation_name+')'};
  }

  @each $prefix in moz, webkit {
    @-#{$prefix}-keyframes #{$animation_name} {
      @content;
    }
  }

  @keyframes #{$animation_name} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

For the second one, the first thing you can do is to use an autoprefixer mixin such as [this one made by Hugo Giraudel](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/mixin-prefix-properties/):

```
@mixin prefix($declarations, $prefixes: ()) {
  @each $property, $value in $declarations {
    @each $prefix in $prefixes {
      #{'-' + $prefix + '-' + $property}: $value;
    }

    // Output standard non-prefixed declaration
    #{$property}: $value;
  }
}
```

And then include it into `@mixin animation`:

```
@mixin animation (
  $animation_name,
  $duration,
  $isGlobal: false,
  $animation_timing_function: linear,
  $delay: 0,
  $fillmode: forwards,
  $direction: normal
) {
  @if $isGlobal {
    :global {
      @include prefix((
        animation-name: $animation_name,
        animation-duration: $duration,
        animation-timing-function: $animation_timing_function,
        animation-delay: $delay,
        animation-fill-mode: $fillmode,
        animation-direction: $direction
      ), webkit moz);
    }
  }
  @else {
    @include prefix((
      animation-name: $animation_name,
      animation-duration: $duration,
      animation-timing-function: $animation_timing_function,
      animation-delay: $delay,
      animation-fill-mode: $fillmode,
      animation-direction: $direction
    ), webkit moz);
  }
}
```

Comment: It works. I just had to remove `@` from `@-#{$prefix}-keyframes #{$animation_name}`. It was giving me an error. Rest of the works flawlessly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Really? I am surprised it give you an error as it compiles right on my side. I am glad if it helped!

Comment: Oh, alright! I am not sure why but it wasn't accepting `@`